# how to group by column and summarise by own function in Python

Tags: python, r, pandas, group-by

let df be our test dataframe from Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar','foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                   'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three','two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                   'C' : np.random.randn(8),
                   'D' : np.random.randn(8)})
```

what i want to do now is actually to group by let's say column `A`, something like:

```
df.groupby(['A'])['C'].sum()
```

that works fine. Now instead of using `sum()` I want to apply a own function to summarise the data in an efficient way.

The equivalent in R would be:

```
require(plyr); require(dplyr)

df = data.frame(A = c('foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar','foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'),
                B = c('one', 'one', 'two', 'three','two', 'two', 'one', 'three'),
                C = rnorm(8),
                D = rnorm(8))
```

with for example this function called `myfun`:

```
myfun <- function(x){sum(x**2)}
```

then:

```
df %>% 
   group_by(A) %>% 
   summarise(result = myfun(C))
```

I hope the question was clear enough. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either use [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) and place your custom function in a lambda, e.g.

```
>>> df.groupby('A').C.agg(lambda x: x.pow(2).sum())
A
bar    3.787664
foo    2.448404
Name: C, dtype: float64
```

Or you could define it separately and pass it to `agg`.

```
def sum2(x):
    return x.pow(2).sum()


>>> df.groupby('A').C.agg(sum2)
A
bar    3.787664
foo    2.448404
Name: C, dtype: float64
```

Note also that `agg` accepts lots of things for the function argument so it is fairly flexible. [From the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html), the `arg` function used for aggregating groups can at the moment be a:

- string cythonized function name
- function
- list of functions
- dict of columns -> functions
- nested dict of names -> dicts of functions

Comment: @ivan7707 True. I find it offers less fine control than `agg` on GroupBy objects though, which is why I used `agg` - e.g. passing multiple functions, certain functions to certain columns, etc.